# Multiple insert and select into a single query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there a way to convert this multiple insert and select into a single statement only?

```
INSERT INTO `subject` (`subject_code`, `student_id`)
   SELECT 'mathematics', student_id FROM student;
INSERT INTO `subject` (`subject_code`, `company_id`)
   SELECT 'science', student_id FROM student;
INSERT INTO `subject` (`subject_code`, `company_id`)
   SELECT 'chemistry', student_id FROM student;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `union all` or `union` (depends on your data)

```
INSERT INTO `subject` (`subject_code`, `student_id`)
(SELECT 'mathematics' as subjectcode, student_id FROM student 
union all
SELECT 'science', student_id FROM student 
union all
SELECT 'chemistry', student_id FROM student);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `cross join` as well:

```
INSERT INTO `subject` (`subject_code`, `student_id`)
   SELECT sub.subject, s.student_id
   FROM student s CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT 'mathematics' as subject UNION ALL
         SELECT 'science' as subject UNION ALL
         SELECT 'chemistry' as subject
        ) sub;
```